# jbuilder with If Condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4, jbuilder

I am trying to display a `key-value` pair on some condition in the jbuilder like as follows

```
json.id plan.id
json.title plan.title
json.description plan.description
json.plan_date plan.plan_date.iso8601
json.start_time plan.start_time.strftime("%I:%M %p") if !plan.start_time.present?
```

**Error**

````
NoMethodError at /api/plans/16
==============================

> undefined method `strftime' for nil:NilClass

app/views/api/v1/plans/_plan.json.jbuilder, line 5
--------------------------------------------------

``` ruby
    1   json.id plan.id
    2   json.title plan.title
    3   json.description plan.description
    4   json.plan_date plan.plan_date.iso8601
>   5   json.start_time plan.start_time.strftime("%I:%M %p") if !plan.start_time.present?
````

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, the inline `if` modifier don't work with jubilder. I do write it like

```
if plan.start_time.present?
  json.start_time plan.start_time.strftime("%I:%M %p")
end
```

Comment: am still getting this :( > undefined method `strftime' for nil:NilClass

Comment: @HarshaMV Yes, because logic was wrong. I fixed it now. You don't need to use `!`, that is misleading with what you are doing.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are not using parenthesis properly and therefore your `if` block is not evaluated properly.

Writing

```
json.start_time plan.start_time.strftime("%I:%M %p") if !plan.start_time.present?
```

is equivalent to:

```
json.start_time(plan.start_time.strftime("%I:%M %p") if !plan.start_time.present?)
```

the correct way of writing it is:

```
json.start_time(plan.start_time.strftime("%I:%M %p")) if !plan.start_time.present?
```

inline `if` modifiers work also on jbuilder.